# OPOS not working on 64 bit system

Tags: 64-bit, point-of-sale, opos

Anyone have experience with OPOS? I can't get my app to recognize the LDNs for the devices running on a 64 bit machine.

I've got down to the point where I know that the OleforRetail stuff is now under Wow6432Node in the Registry. I suspect the common controls can't find the LDN because of this. Is there any kind of workaround?

Failing that, is there a centralized OPOS development forum somewhere?

BTW: I work with the common controls supplied by Monroe Consulting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are you using to develop your application?

If you are using .NET you need to set it to be compiled as a 32-bit version.

Platform target: x86 on the c# project settings.

If a program is 32 bit or 64 bit decides where in the registry it looks for values. 
All the OPOS com objects are 32-bit, so if you use a 64-bit program it will not find any information about them.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem that I had is that the LDNs weren't being found by my app. Well it turns out that you have to run the OPOS driver configuration software as administrator to get it to manipulate the 32 bit section of the registry properly. The LDNs just weren't being written in the right place in the registry so my app couldn't find them.